# android disable clipping recyclerview's item

Tags: android, android-layout, android-recyclerview

[image: To-be and As-is]

First picture describe what I want, and second picture is what I got.

Black rectangle means `RecyclerView`, dark red means it's item. Navy is `ImageView`.

I tried clipChildren on parent viewgroup where recyclerview belong to.

Is there any wany to achieve that ? (I also tried animation)

```
val animation = TranslateAnimation(
    Animation.ABSOLUTE, 0f,
    Animation.ABSOLUTE, 0f,
    Animation.ABSOLUTE, 0f,
    Animation.ABSOLUTE, -dpToPixel(21f, itemView.context)
)
animation.duration = 0

imageView.startAnimation(animation)
```

--- EDIT ---

**Activity Layout**

```xml
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
                                               android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                               android:layout_height="60dp"
                                               android:background="@android:color/black"
                                               app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
                                               app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
                                               app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"/>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

**ViewHolder Layout**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                                                   xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
                                                   android:orientation="vertical"
                                                   android:layout_width="50dp"
                                                   android:layout_height="50dp">


    <!-- image -->
    <View android:id="@+id/dummy"
          android:layout_width="0dp"
          android:layout_height="0dp"
          android:background="@android:color/holo_green_dark"
          app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
          app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
          app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
          app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent" />

    <!-- marker here -->
    <View android:layout_width="20dp"
          android:layout_height="20dp"
          android:translationX="-5dp"
          android:translationY="-5dp"
          android:background="@android:color/holo_red_dark"
          app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
          app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

[image]

Note that I can't give more height than 60dp and inner item has fixed height (50dp).

[image]

Comment: So do you want a view that looks like he is on top of the `RecyclerView` item?

Comment: @TamirAbutbul exactly

Comment: Check my answer @Slander

Comment: Your items are always constraint by your RecyclerView. Maybe you can give padding to your RecyclerView in order to have more space between items and boundry of RecyclerView.

Comment: The _RecyclerView_ is clipping its children. too. Set `android:clipChildren="false"` on the _RecyclerView_.

Comment: @Cheticamp thanks for answer, I set clipChildren=false to activity and recyclerview it worked.

Comment: @Cheticamp post your answer to **answer** to let me accept yours.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In your example, the view holder layout is contained within the *RecyclerView* and the *RecyclerView* is contained within a_ConstraintLayout_.

ConstraintLayout
----> RecyclerView
--------> ConstraintLayout (view holder)
------------> ImageView

According to the [documentation for *clipChildren*](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.html#attr_android:clipChildren)

> android:clipChildren
>
> Defines whether a child is limited to draw inside of its bounds or not.

You want the view holder to be able to draw the *ImageView* outside the bounds of the view holder **and** the *RecyclerView* to draw the view holder outside of the bounds of the *RecyclerView*. To do this, you will need to set `android:clipChildren="false"` on the *RecyclerView* **and** the top-level *ConstraintLayout*.

Comment: **PLEASE NOTE** I had to set BOTH clipChildren **and clipToPadding** as false.  And I had to do that all the way up from the recycler view.  Hope it helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

With [ConstraintLayout](https://developer.android.com/training/constraint-layout) you can achieve the "view over view" in a few seconds:

All you need to do is to make the proper constraints, the upper view will be constrained to another view and he will be on top of him.

**Something like this:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
  xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher_background"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    tools:text="Lower view" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/button2"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/button2"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/button2"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/button2"
    tools:text="top" />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

**And it will look like this:**

[image]

And this is how you can put 1 view on top on another view, now all left for you to do is implement it for your case.

Comment: sorry for my ambiguous question, since `ImageView` is item of recyclerview, so I can't use `match_parent`. In this case, I'll assume inner view has 50dp x 50dp size

Comment: you don't have so use `match_parent`, how does it relate to my answer? could you elaborate?

Comment: Edited my questions, please check

Comment: It's not so clear to me, do you want your items to be like the lowest image?